# django-registration "reset" redirects to "login"?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

**django-registration 'reset' doesn't get processed**

Using django-registration 1.0 under Django 1.6 . Everything (register, login, logoff, change) works as it should except "reset" which just redirects to the login form.

My urls.py looks like this :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^spellweb/', include('spellweb.urls', namespace="spellweb")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
)
```

And the url associated with the 'Reset' link is :

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/password/reset/
```

When that url is presented to the server a 302 is returned which sends the browser off to the login page like this :

```
[24/Feb/2014 22:55:00] "GET /accounts/password/reset/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[24/Feb/2014 22:55:01] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/accounts/password/reset/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1795
[24/Feb/2014 22:55:01] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[24/Feb/2014 22:55:01] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1780
[24/Feb/2014 22:55:01] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1782
```

Just to make myself entirely clear the problem isn't just that the reset form isn't processed - the system won't even serve a 'reset' form .

So ... I'd be greatful if someone would suggest why this might be happening and/or confirm that they get some other result using Django 1.6/django-registration 1.0.

Thanks

---

*More information pertinent to Mario Gudelj:*
Yes I believe I am using the auth_urls you reference. The reason I say this is that the 'registration.backends.default.urls' referenced within my urls.py in turn references 'registration.auth_urls' . I don't know why that's not producing the effect I would expect. I would like to be sure that the url object within that auth_urls is being used but I can't find a way of establishing which django.conf.urls.patterns instance is active for any given request - that would be great if I could find a way of doing that.

---

*More information pertinent to comment of Alasdair:*
The ROOT_URLCONF points at the urls.py shown above which in its entirety is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

#url(r'^accounts/', include('auth_urls')),

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^spellweb/', include('spellweb.urls', namespace="spellweb")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
)
~
```

The  `spellweb.urls` referenced there is as follows (nothing very much due to trying to get registration working before doing anything else) ...

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from spellweb import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
)
#    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
#    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
~
```

The `registration.backends.default.urls` refernenced there is as per :https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/backends/default/urls.py?at=default and that in turn references : https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/auth_urls.py?at=default

Comment: Is that your entire `urls.py`? The log shows that `/style.css` and `/favicon.ico` are being redirected, which suggests that there's another pattern that is matching these urls as well.

Comment: @Alasdair : Thanks for your comment. I will try to respond by editing the question but in short the base url includes references to other url's. Now that you ask about the style.css/favicon.ico at least at the moment I'm not sure how that resolution occurs (should explain/excuse that it's rather late here maybe I could work that ou in the morning).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/auth_urls.py?at=default?

It seems for that auth_urls.py has that URL and it's using Django's generic password_reset view from django.contrib.auth.views.

Make sure that you haven't changed the URL structure in that file and that this code is still in there:

```
url(r'^password/reset/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset,
                           name='auth_password_reset'),
```

Seems like you have somehow managed to place login_required decorator around that view.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I appreciate it. I will edit the question to include an answer to your question.